# Mesclar executavel c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, .exe, embed, setup

Tenho 2 programas Exe e gostaria de mesclar.

1 Exe de Software de Gerenciamento

2 EXE MongoDB

Para que 1 EXE funcione, têm que estar totalmente configurado o MongoDB com o banco implementado em diretorios especificos. Atualmente as configurações e intalação do MongoDB é feito manualmente.

Gostaria de Criar apenas um Executavel !!! onde o Mesmo Instale MongoDB> Cria Pasta do BD > Cria Path do Mongo DB > Transfere o Banco de Dados p/ MongoDB > Inicie os Serviço do MongoDB > (E AGORA QUE EXECUTE 1 EXE SFW DE GERENCIAMENTO ) INSTALAÇÃO PADRÃO DO 1 EXE.

Oque eu consegui fazer. 
Consegui apenas trazer os Executaveis atraves do Button1(1.exe) e Button2(2.exe) 
(Consegui incluir[embedded exe] eles no Projeto C# dentro de resources e chamar eles atraves do button).

Qual é melhor forma de criar um SETUP que inclua dois EXE.

Tipo o site do Ninite.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia amigo,

É simples, crie uma aplicação que execute primeiramente o configurador do MongoDb, usando o `WaitForExit()`. Logo após você pode executar o instalador do Software de gerenciamento. Segue a lógica do `WaitForExit()`.

```js
var process = Process.Start(...);
process.WaitForExit();
```

Documentação: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.7.2

Obs: Para verificar a instalação 1, você pode verificar a existência do mesmo no computador ou a existência de uma pasta.